# How to run ASP.NET MVC 2 (not 1 which is default)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono

This might be a stupid question but how to update System.Web.Mvc dll which is 1.0 right now?

I'm using the latest Mono 2.6.7 and MonoDevelop 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this link: http://go-mono.com/forums/#nabble-td1595299